# Unable to compile .tsx files in Angular16 Project

Tags: angular, react-native, react-dom, angular16, graphiql

I recently migrated my angular9 project to angular16. In my existing angular 9 project I had some .tsx files which were compiling successfully during npm build. However after migrating to angular 16 getting this error -

`Could not resolve "../../components/graphiql/graphiql.component.tsx" from "dist/my-library/esm2022/lib/pages/create-template/create-template.component.mjs"

@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr  doesn't seem to support .tsx files. `

Tried updating the version of react packages, angular packges, tried all the combinations in tsconfig.json Tried updating angular builder.

angular builder - @angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr

package.json

angular packages

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^16.0.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "16.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.1.0",
"@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/elements": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
```

React packages

```
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"@types/react": "^16.9.0",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
```

graphiql packages

```
"graphiql": "^0.17.5",
"graphiql-explorer": "^0.6.2",
"graphql": "^14.3.1",
"graphql-language-service-interface": "2.8.2",
"graphql-language-service-parser": "1.9.0",
"graphql-language-service-utils": "2.5.2",
"graphql-ws": "^4.2.2",
```

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "ES2020",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "ES2020",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "traceResolution":true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
   ......}
```

Comment: Required code formatting

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `.tsx` for angular component `graphiql.component.tsx` that needs to change to `.ts` and call the react component using `React.createElement`

```
   const element = React.createElement(ReactComponent, {});
   ReactDom.render(element, this.containerRef.nativeElement);
```